# enter win32 desktop from metro app at its startup

Tags: c#, microsoft-metro, desktop, launcher

I want to enter win32 desktop from a metro app when launch the metro app (press the app's tile on metro startup screen). One way is to open a file (e.g. a TXT file) when start the metro app. I add the following code logic into OnLaunched, sometimes it can open the file and enter desktop, but sometimes, it doesn't. Could someone help me? (just create a blank app in VS2012).

```
async protected override void OnLaunched(LaunchActivatedEventArgs args) {
// Do not repeat app initialization when already running, just ensure that the window     //is active
if (args.PreviousExecutionState == ApplicationExecutionState.Running)
{
    Window.Current.Activate();
    return;
}
if (args.PreviousExecutionState == ApplicationExecutionState.Terminated)
{
    //TODO: Load state from previously suspended application
}

// Create a Frame to act navigation context and navigate to the first page
// var rootFrame = new Frame();
if (!rootFrame.Navigate(typeof(MainPage)))
{
    throw new Exception("Failed to create initial page");
}

// Place the frame in the current Window and ensure that it is active
Window.Current.Content = rootFrame;
Window.Current.Activate();
{
    string txtfile = @"Assets\a.txt";
    var file = await Windows.ApplicationModel.Package.Current.InstalledLocation.GetFileAsync(txtfile);

    if (file != null)
    {
         bool success = await Windows.System.Launcher.LaunchFileAsync(file);
         if (success)
         {
         }
         else
         {
         }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Have you tried creating a WinForms app that immediately exits upon starting, and launching that?

Answer (score 0):

[BatRT](http://isys-labs.com/batrt/) allows you to execute a batch file from a metro app. This could be used to run any desktop application from a metro app. As soon as the metro app starts execute a batch file to run your desired desktop application.